# make embedded google sheet scroll to the end of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have embedded a single google sheet into a wordpress webpage and would like to have it scrolled to last valued row. The default is it is showing the 1st row. The scroll bar is visible and it can be manually scrolled to the end but the sheet updates automatically using forms and everytime the webpage is opened I would like it to scroll to the newest data at the end of the sheet.

[image]

Here are the EMBED setting's I'm using for thIS

```
[googleapps domain="docs" dir="spreadsheets/d/e/XXXXX/pubhtml" 
query="gid=0&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false" 
width="320" height="150" /]
```

Does anyone know if there is a scroll parameter or other method for this?
Thanks

Comment: A workaround would be to embed a second sheet that is a "view" of the raw data. On this second sheet, you would use a formula like `=query` to select all the data columns, but sorted in reverse order, to place the newest data at the top.

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch - that worked like a charm! I was already using a second sheet to exclude some data but when I added the =query command in additional columns to duplicate the data it allowed me sort exactly as I was wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used @tehhowch's workaround, but with standard gs/excel functions instead of `select` query, and **without using a column to sort by**. The result is this:

`=SORT(FILTER('Лист1'!A1:K;NOT(ISBLANK('Лист1'!C1:C)));FILTER(ROW('Лист1'!C1:C);NOT(ISBLANK('Лист1'!C1:C)));FALSE)`

In my case I had endless list of rows generated by the IFTTT bot on the sheet 'Лист1' and I wanted to sort backwards (reverse), that is, **flip the sheet** so that the last row became the first, regardless of what data was in the cells. So, this is a universal solution.

In this formula:

- first `FILTER` is used for filter all the rows that are filled (not blank) in the entire range A:K, by column C to determine the range I want to flip,
- second `FILTER` filters the row numbers that are returned by the `ROW` function from the same range, which are used to sort the range by these numbers in the `SORT` function (rows count from the first and second filters must be equal),
- `FALSE` flag - for descending sort.